# Porque me manda NaN al hacer una operación de multiplicación?

Tags: javascript, html5

como estan? necesito su ayuda para resolver un pequeño problema quizas parezca tonto pero estoy empezando y bueno no encuentro solución. El problema esta en que cuando hago la multiplicacion me manda NaN y no me da el resultado. Se que `NaN` significa que no es un número, pero me manda eso aun asi ingrese numeros en el input. Agradecería que sea hecho unicamente con Javascript. Muchas gracias!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="multx.js"></script>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="valor1" />
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="text" name="valor2" />
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="text" name="result" readonly />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn" value="Calcular"  onclick="Calcular()"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
function Calcular() {
  let valor1 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("num1"));
  let valor2 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("num2"));

  let resultado = valor1 * valor2

  document.getElementsByName("result")[0].value = resultado;

}
```

Comment: Por que en ningún momento accedes a la propiedad value de los 2 inputs, realiza eso por ejemplo donde los pasas por el método parseFloat

Comment: En vez de `getElementsByName("num1")`  debe ser `getElementsByName("valor1")`, lo mismo para el otro

Comment: gracias por los dos comentarios, ya cambie el nombre que tenia mal puesto en el `getelementsbyname ("valor1")`, y aun asi me manda el NaN.

Comment: tambien intente hacer lo que @BetaM me recomendo de oinerle el `.value` despues de los parseFloat y no me funciona aun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que estas usando `getElementsByName()` lo siguiente devuelve una lista de `NODOS` del documento supongamos que tuvieras varios `inputs` con nombre `"valor1"` entonces `getElementsByName('valor1')` va devolver la cantidad de nodos que existan, si tuvieras dos en el documento, te va dar dos `NODOS`, luego tu debes recorrer esos nodos y verificar de cual de ellos quieres recuperar el atributo `value`, en tu caso como solo tienes un `NODO` input con el nombre `"valor1"` y `"valor2"` es suficiente que recuperes el elemento en la posición 0 `[0]` de la siguiente manera:

```
function Calcular() {
  // con [0] obtenemos el NODO en al posición 0, luego recuperamos su atributo value.
  let valor1 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('valor1')[0].value);
  let valor2 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('valor2')[0].value);

  let resultado = valor1 * valor2;

  document.getElementsByName('result')[0].value = resultado;

}
```

Espero esto te ayude.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @Diego-1743 si me funciono. gracias por la explicacion tambien muy buena. y bueno ya que mencionas que cuando uso getelementsbyname me busca todos los nodos de ese getelementby name , entonces puedo hacer una tabla en la que me busque todos los valores dentro de celdas con el mismo `name` y multiplicarlas y sumarlas?

Comment: Sí!, solo pon el mismo nombre a los nodos, luego obtén la lista de nodos con `getelementsbyname()` con un `for each` recorres el `array` y de cada uno obtienes el atributo `value`, finalmente multiplicas poco a poco en una variable y luego la imprimes, no olvides agregar una validación en donde si lo ingresado no es un número pues el usuario deba corregir.